# Найдите в предложениях лексические ошибки и исправьте их.

Tags: лексика

1. Опыт использования такой формы работы показывает, что в основном студенты неформально подходят к выполнению заданного задания. 2. Человек тоже артефакт, т.к. он становится человеком путем социализации, культура усваивается личностью в процессе социализации и представляет собой совокупность общепринятых образчиков поведения, мышления и мироощущения, а также индивидуально значимые действия. 3. Стали «в цене» профессионалы, имеющие опыт и знающие свой труд до мельчайших нюансов.

Comment: @pantera1979, Предложите, пожалуйста, свой вариант ответа на данное задание.

Comment: Опыт использования такой формы работы показывает, что в основном студенты неформально подходят к выполнению данного задания. Правильно?

Comment: Профессионалы, имеющие опыт и знающие свой труд до малейших деталей теперь «в цене».

Comment: второе затрудняюсь

Answer (score 1):

Опыт использования такой формы работы показывает, что в основном студенты неформально подходят к выполнению ПОЛУЧЕННОГО задания.

Человек тоже артефакт, т.к. он становится человеком путем социализации:  культура усваивается личностью в процессе социализации и представляет собой совокупность общепринятых ОБРАЗЦОВ поведения, мышления и мироощущения, а также индивидуально значимых действий.  (Образчик в значении пример  –  это разговорный стиль).

Стали «в цене» профессионалы, имеющие опыт и знающие своё ДЕЛО до мельчайших нюансов.